# validate two fields shouldn't equal to each other yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

i have a form where i can create football match. there are 3 fields `home team` (drop down list, where user selects a team), `away team`(also drop down list) and score field. so `<option>` tag value equals `team_id`.
[image: printscreen]

for example, i can choose home team `juventus`, away team `milan` and score `2:2`. problem is, i should validate if home team not equals to away team, so user shouldn't create football match team against itself, for example `juventus` vs `juventus`. how should i validate these fields(home_team, away_team) not equal to each other?

rules method

```
 public function rules()
 {
    return [
        [['score'], 'required'],
        ['home_team_id', 'required', 'message' => 'Please choose a home team'],
        ['away_team_id', 'required', 'message' => 'Please choose a away team'],
        ['score', 'match', 'pattern' => '/^\d{1,2}(:\d{1,2})?$/'],
        ['home_team_id', 'compare', 'compareValue' => 'away_team_id', 'operator' => '!=', 'message' => 'Please choose a different teams'],
        [['away_team_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Team::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['away_team_id' => 'id']],
        [['home_team_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Team::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['home_team_id' => 'id']],
        [['round_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Round::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['round_id' => 'id']],
    ];
  }
```

my form

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'home_team_id')->dropDownList($items, $params)->label('Home Team');?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'away_team_id')->dropDownList($items, $params)->label('Away Team');?>

<div class="hidden">
    <?= $form->field($model, 'round_id')->hiddenInput()->label(''); ?>
</div>

<?= $form->field($model, 'score')->textInput([
    'maxlength' => true,
    'placeholder' => 'seperate goals with colon, for example 2:1'
]) ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

`$items` array contains teams(names and ids)

Comment: you should use 'compareAttribute' instead of 'compareValue' in the rules method. ['rango_desde', 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'rango_hasta', 'operator' => '<', 'type' => 'number'],

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use Compare Validator: [Docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-core-validators.html#compare)

Comment: thanks for reply, i already tried it. `['home_team_id', 'compare', 'compareValue' => 'away_team_id', 'operator' => '==', 'message' => 'Please choose a different teams'],` but when i choose home team it immediately shows error  `Please choose a different teams` despite i haven'n chosen away team

Comment: i also tried it,but now it doesnt show any error, even if there are the same teams

Comment: Im new here, so i used enter and... :)

So:
2. Use `'enableClientValidaton' => false` to not validate by js
3. Use ajax validation - it will validate when u try to send form :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129920/discussion-between-yupik-and--).

Comment: @Yupik Links can change or be removed therefore invalidating this answer. You should add the relevant parts from the link into the answer.

Comment: @topher Well, it's official Yii2 docs, but thanks, i will apply to this next time :)

Answer (score 1):

```
['home_team_id', 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'away_team_id', 'operator' => '!=', 'message' => 'Please choose a different teams'],
```

change comparevalue to CompareAttribute